# How do I assign active links using php

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, navigation

I have set up this Wordpress website: (http://www.eureka-marketing.co.uk/drive)

and would like the main navigation links to remain active for each page (ie. remain blue once the user is on the current page)

Thing is I have used a custom menu, therefore the 'current-page-item' within the theme I have used is ignoring the custom CSS.

Is there some coding I need to insert into the header.php where the links are ?

please help

Comment: So you have a custom menu not built via WordPress but put manually into the theme? If that's the case, you'll have to do something along the lines of fetching the url and mapping it to the right menu item and appending a class to keep it blue.

If by custom menu, you mean custom links or something along those lines, then you should use the absolute path url and WordPress should technically pick it up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, yes it's a custom menu just inserted into the header.php file. Is this something that needs to be done in the CSS file?

Comment: You could use CSS to manipulate the color after using PHP to manually mark the current page as class X, where class X has the properties to keep it blue.

Comment: would you be able to show me an example? that would be really helpful